# Phonegap - js prompt showing numeric pad

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, prompt

I'm developing an application for Android using Phonegap.

```
var customTime = prompt("Enter custom time");
```

Is there a way to show numeric pad when user click on prompt's text input to enter time?
Now, when user click on it regular pad showing, and he must to click on number button first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot change that. because it doesn't allow you to specify the input type anywhere.

**My suggestion**:

- Use a div to show the prompt like box, with some z-index adjustments so that a similar kind of prompt box can be made from some html+css code. In that you can define a input field with type = number.

ie `<input type=”number” value ="" id="something" />`